# #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

im having touble making an insert trigger .
the trigger goes like this :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `InsertTrigger`//
CREATE TRIGGER `InsertTrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `Chen_Country`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

                 INSERT INTO Country_Area (Area,Country_id)
                 VALUES (NEW.Area, (Select Country_id from Chen_Country) );
end
```

my schema is that i have chen_country which is a table with 15 attributes about countries and i want that on insert to it the db will automatically update country_area in country_id and Area which are both insert as a row in chen_country as a part of the 15 attributes which are in a row there.

now after i implemented the trigger i get the error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row 
and i cant insert anything to chen_country? what to change in the trigger in order to get what i want ?
thx in advance  ...

Comment: `Select Country_id from Chen_Country` returns more than one row. It can't do that.

Comment: so just to add distinct would solve this ?

Comment: No. That will still returns multiple rows. This query just won't work.

Comment: this insert query does not make sense, since even if you select.. limit1 it will select any coountry id which may not be the one for area.

Comment: That's not correct way of inserting; even if you say `Select Country_id from Chen_Country limit 1` every time it's going to get you the same value (most probably); moreover which may not be accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use NEW.Country_id in the trigger rather than subselect.

```
INSERT INTO Country_Area (Area,Country_id)
             VALUES (NEW.Area, NEW.Country_id);
```

Comment: yeah that just made me something about primary key error before when i used it now for some reason its ok.
this solved it : 
 INSERT INTO `DbMysql08`.`Country_Area` (`Area`, `Country_id`) VALUES (New.Area,New.Country_id);
so its as you said

Comment: @user3573265 If you create BEFORE INSERT trigger the id (auto generated) doesn't exist. For the AFTER INSERT trigger it's available.